# On itemselectedListener not working with custom list adapter

Tags: android, android-listview

nothing happens when I click on item of list view here is code

```
@SuppressLint("ParserError")
public class DinerList extends Activity implements Comparator<CanteenTagEntry>,
        OnItemSelectedListener {
    List<CanteenTagEntry> dinerlist;
    int size;
    int[] arr;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.diner_list);
        ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        Context con = getApplicationContext();
        DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(con);
        ICanteenLogRepository repository = dbHelper.getCanteenLogRepository();

        try {
            dinerlist = repository.total();
            Collections.sort(dinerlist, new DinerList());
            Collections.sort(dinerlist, new sortbyuser());
            Collections.sort(dinerlist, new sortbycompany());

            size = dinerlist.size();
            arr = new int[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                CanteenTagEntry tagentry = dinerlist.get(i);
                int b = tagentry.getId();
                System.out.print(b);
                arr[i] = tagentry.getId();
                System.out.print(arr[i]);
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.d("DinerList", "Unable to retrieve diner list", e);
        }
        CanteenAdapter adapter = new CanteenAdapter(this,
                R.layout.listview_item_row,
                (ArrayList<CanteenTagEntry>) dinerlist);
        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public class CanteenAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CanteenTagEntry> {

        Context context;
        int layoutResourceId;
        ArrayList<CanteenTagEntry> data = (ArrayList<CanteenTagEntry>) dinerlist;

        public CanteenAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
                ArrayList<CanteenTagEntry> data) {
            super(context, layoutResourceId, dinerlist);
            this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
            this.context = context;
            this.data = (ArrayList<CanteenTagEntry>) dinerlist;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            RouteHolder holder = null;
            if (row == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context)
                        .getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
                holder = new RouteHolder();
                holder.txtName1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.Title1);
                holder.txtName2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.Title2);
                holder.txtName3 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.Title3);

                row.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (RouteHolder) row.getTag();
            }
            CanteenTagEntry tagentry = data.get(position);
            String idcolor = tagentry.getUser().getIdcolor().toString();

            try {
                holder.txtName1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(idcolor));
                holder.txtName2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(idcolor));
                holder.txtName3.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(idcolor));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                holder.txtName1.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                holder.txtName2.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                holder.txtName3.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            }

            holder.txtName1.setText(tagentry.getUser().getUserType().getName());
            holder.txtName2.setText(tagentry.getUser().getCompany().getName());
            holder.txtName3.setText(tagentry.getUser().getFirstName());

            return row;
        }

        class RouteHolder {
            TextView txtName1;
            TextView txtName2;
            TextView txtName3;
            TextView txtName4;

        }

    }

    @Override
    public int compare(CanteenTagEntry o1, CanteenTagEntry o2) {
        return o1.getUser().getFirstName()
                .compareTo(o2.getUser().getFirstName());

    }

    public class sortbyuser implements Comparator<CanteenTagEntry> {

        @Override
        public int compare(CanteenTagEntry lhs, CanteenTagEntry rhs) {
            return lhs.getUser().getUserType().getName()
                    .compareTo(rhs.getUser().getUserType().getName());

        }

    }

    public class sortbycompany implements Comparator<CanteenTagEntry> {

        @Override
        public int compare(CanteenTagEntry lhs, CanteenTagEntry rhs) {
            return lhs.getUser().getCompany().getName()
                    .compareTo(rhs.getUser().getCompany().getName());

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position,
            long ide) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, ide);
        CanteenTagEntry tagentry = null;
        int pos = position;
        int id = arr[pos];
        int userid = 0;
        Context con = getApplicationContext();
        DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(con);
        ICanteenLogRepository repository = dbHelper.getCanteenLogRepository();
        try {
            tagentry = repository.Retrieve(id);
            userid = tagentry.getUser().getId();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            StartFood food = new StartFood(id, userid);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: I think OnItemSelectedListener is works perfectly for spinner. For the ListView you can use OnItemClickedListener

Comment: @nick onitemClickedListener is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i thin you need to used

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


               // do your work here 

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set [`OnItemClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) for your `listView1` as per below and try to run.

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        CanteenTagEntry tagentry = null;
        int pos = position;
        int id = arr[pos];
        int userid = 0;
        Context con = getApplicationContext();
        DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(con);
        ICanteenLogRepository repository = dbHelper.getCanteenLogRepository();

        try 
        {
            tagentry = repository.Retrieve(id);
            userid = tagentry.getUser().getId();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try 
        {
            StartFood food = new StartFood(id, userid);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before returning the **row** Set the listener to the row like this.

```
row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                      // your code  
                }
            });
```